Adding cells to raster layer after merging raster layers in QGIS
The issue
I have a raster layer that represents a river catchment. I want to use it in software that requires the exit of the catchment to be at the edge of the extent. To do this I need to add some raster cells along the outflow as the catchment currently does not touch the exit of the catchment.
Data
This is the raster and the red polygon is where the water needs to extend along. It can follow this polygon or it can be just a straight line of cells. The raster resolution is roughly 10m x 10m and is a GeoTIFF.

Current methods
I've tried rasterizing the polygon to match the catchment raster resolution (10x10m) and merging together. However, the cells don't seem to align and the cells from the rasterized outflow disappear from the merged outflow except the cells that are outside the extent of the original catchment raster.
Any advice?
